# Prevent screencapture from capturing app screen on MacOSX

Tags: macos, screenshot

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent users of my app from snapping a screenshot of any of my app's windows.  I'm mainly concerned with users automating screenshots using /usr/sbin/screencapture with cron.  At first I thought there was no way to prevent it but then I discovered that there are some apps that are doing something that causes the screenshot to be all black or the color of the desktop.  If I could pull that off I would be golden.  I've seen other posts that touch on the subject but nothing that actually works in my situation.  I'm running catalina.  Any and all insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSWindowSharingNone` of `sharingType` property on `NSWindow`

> setSharingType: specifies whether the window content can be read
> and/or written from another process. The default sharing type is
> NSWindowSharingReadOnly, which means other processes can read the
> window content (eg. for window capture) but cannot modify it.  If you
> set your window sharing type to NSWindowSharingNone, so that the
> content cannot be captured, your window will also not be able to
> participate in a number of system services, so this setting should be
> used with caution. If you set your window sharing type to
> NSWindowSharingReadWrite, other processes can both read and modify the
> window content.

```
@property NSWindowSharingType sharingType API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5));
```